# Android Parse "invalid session token" error

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am new to android and I am stuck on what seems to be a simple problem to fix but I just don't know what I am doing wrong! All I need to do is sign up a user, for some reason the e is never equal to null and therefore it goes straight to the else part which gives me the invalid session token message. Here is the code for the signup part, I looked at it thousands of times!:

```
protected EditText mUsername;
protected EditText mPassword;
protected EditText mEmail;
protected Button mSignUpButton;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up_manager);

    mUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
    mPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
    mEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailField);
    mSignUpButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signupButton);

    mSignUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String username = mUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
            String email = mEmail.getText().toString();

            //trims the spaces
            username = username.trim();
            password = password.trim();
            email = email.trim();

            //if one of the text edits is empty send them a message with a                                    title with an ok button.
            if(username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty()){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUpManagerActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.signup_error_message)
                        .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);

                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
            else {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);//the progress circle is active.

                //creating a new parse user.
                ParseUser pUser = new ParseUser();
                pUser.setUsername(username);
                pUser.setPassword(password);
                pUser.setEmail(email);

                pUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);//the progress circle is not active.
                        if (e == null) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpManagerActivity.this, LoginManagerActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUpManagerActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                    .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);

                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });



}
```

Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have all parse required permissions?

Comment: Print `e.getMessage()` to find out what the error is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First post here but I had the same error. Correct me if I am wrong but I believe the issue also for me was that I could create the user once and then get invalid session tokens afterwards. I think its due to the fact that the "session" on the Parse Website's end is still logged in even though you can close and re-run the app on your end.

By putting the following code before I try to create a new parse user I fixed my issue.

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
currentUser.logOut();
```

Hope that helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

1.this is due to deleting the session without log out so all you have to do is

type the below code

```
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
user.LogOut();
```

2.if the first not work go to setting of your emulator and go to App select your app then click on Clear Data but be careful this will clear your DB also